# react-jss complex conditional styling

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, jss, react-typescript

Been working with react-jss for a few weeks now and I'm trying to figure out the best way to style some components. I have a lot of conditionals in these components and I'm trying not to make too many new components that share a lot of code. I like that I can put this logic in my styles via JS instead of having to conditional apply classnames like we were doing before.

An example of one of my more complex/meh styles:

```
color:
    props.inactive && (props.buttonType === 'outline' || props.buttonColor === 'red')
    ? colors.greyscaleReg
    : props.buttonColor === 'red'
    ? colors.primaryRed
    : props.buttonType === 'outline'
    ? colors.primaryBlue
    : props.buttonType === 'lightFill'
    ? colors.primaryBlue
    : colors.white,
```

I'm a fan of ternaries so I don't have trouble parsing this, some of my coworkers are not fans of ternaries though, especially when they're nested/chained like this.

Is it advised to move this logic outside of the styles?

One suggestion was to make a function to hold this code and call that function inside the styles (can't use an outside function for the hover and it doesn't calculate it correctly).

And I really don't like this:

```
backgroundColor: () => {
        if (props.inactive) {
          return colors.greyscaleLight;
        }
        if (!props.loading && !props.inactive) {
          if (props.buttonType === 'outline') {
            return colors.secondaryPaleBlue;
          }
          if (props.buttonType === 'lightFill') {
            return colors.secondarySoftBlue;
          }
        } else if (props.buttonColor === 'red') {
          return colors.secondaryDarkRed;
        }
        return colors.darkPrimaryBlue;
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

It is advised to not use too many nested-ternary conditions. The best coding practice in javascript is to avoid nested-ternary as per [eslint - no-nested-ternary linting rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-nested-ternary.html) which is being widely used in almost wherever javascript is being used. [ESLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESLint) is a static code analysis tool for identifying problematic patterns found in JavaScript code.

You can use switch..case or if..else if..else conditional statements.

References:

- [ESLint - official Homepage](https://eslint.org/), [eslint - no-nested-ternary linting rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-nested-ternary.html), [ESLint - wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESLint), [Multiple lines in a ternary operator’s clauses? - sitepoint blog](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/multiple-lines-in-a-ternary-operators-clauses/110769/2)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use a switch because I am comparing strings, well I know it's possible but it's very inneficient.
And I just found out moving to if/else outside the jss breaks the hover rules completely.

Answer (score 0):

Consider separating your conditional logic out from individual styles by using different `className`s for your different button types.

```
const styles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  inactive: { color: ..., ... },
  outline: { color: ..., ... },
  ...
}))

const MyButton = ({ isInactive, buttonType }) => {
  const { inactive, outline, ... } = useStyles(styles)

  const className = [
    isInactive && inactive,
    buttonType === 'outline' && outline,
    ...
  ]
    .filter(Boolean)
    .join(' ')

  return (
    <button className={className}>
      ...
    </button>
  )
}
```

Example uses Material UI/hook-flavor JSS, but principle should be the same for other flavors.